# How to filter some array in a sub-object with object in a json file with jq

Tags: json, jq

I need to filter a JSON with a nested strucutre like below.
All objects in array b where attribute x contains a "z" in the value of x should be filtered out. The rest should stay in the file.

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": [
            {
                "c": "1",
                "x": "aaa",
            },
            {
                "c": "2",
                "x": "aza",
            },
            {
                "c": "7",
                "x": "azb",
            }
        ]
    },
    "d": {
        "e": [
            "1"
        ],
        "f": [
            "2"
        ]
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": [
      {
        "c": "1",
        "x": "aaa"
      }
    ]
  },
  "d": {
    "e": [
      "1"
    ],
    "f": [
      "2"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far and what is your expected output?

Comment: The expected output of jq should be:
{
    "a": {
        "b": [
            {
                "c": "1",
                "x": "aaa",
            },
        ]
    },
    "d": {
        "e": [
            "1"
        ],
        "f": [
            "2"
        ]
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `select` with `contains`:

```
jq '.a.b|=[.[]|select(.x|contains("z")|not)]' file
```